# Filtering index list of a table if a value exists in another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

So I have three tables in my database:

Projects:

```
    [ProjectId]               INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]                  NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [Title]                   NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
```

Applications:

```
    [ApplicationId]  INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [UserId]         NVARCHAR (128)  NOT NULL,
```

Contracts:

```
    [ContractId]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId]     NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [CVR]           NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [StudentId]     NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [IsSigned]      BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
```

The way that the MVC application works is that there is an Index of Projects (relatively simple db.Projects.ToList() method), a student can apply, which creates an Application. When the Employee goes to their project and sees the student's application, he clicks a button to choose the student, creating a new Contract in the database. 
How can I modify

```
List<Project> projectsList = (from p in db.Projects select p).ToList();
```

so that only projects that have not been "contracted" are shown? The contract has the applicationId, when the application can be retrieved, from which the projectId can be retrieved. There should be some kind of way to easily check if the projectID exists in the Contracts table, and if so, should not display that project in the index.

Comment: Out of curiosity... is Project.UserId the same as Contract.CompanyId, and Application.UserId the same as Contract.StudentId? From what you describe, it'd make sense to me that projects are created by companies and students apply for specific projects; and right now I see no scenario where company id in contract is different than id of whoever put the project, and student id in contract is different from id of the student who applied. If it's correct, then CompanyId and StudentId are redundant.

Comment: yes, the Project.UserId is the Id of the company that posts it. The application's UserId is the student's id. Projects are created by companies and students apply like you said. StudentId and CompanyId are foreign keys, they are not redundant because for another feature I have to pull the student/company object in the contract, which is easily done with the Id, rather than storing their data in the contract object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```
List<Project> projectsList = (from p in db.Projects 
from a in db.Applications
on p.ProjectId equals a.ProjectId
from c in db.Contracts
on a.ApplicationId equals c.ApplicationId into CC
from c in CC.DefaultIfEmpty()
where c == null             
select p).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you meant
 (from p in db.Projects
               
                                          join a in db.Applications
                                          on p.ProjectId equals a.ProjectId

                                          join c in db.Contracts
                                          on a.ApplicationId equals c.ApplicationId into CC

                                          from c in CC.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          where c == null


                                          select p).ToList();  
                       ??

Comment: It appears to be filtering even newly created projects from the index

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Project> projectsList =
                db.Projects.Where(
                    p =>
                        !db.Contracts.Join(db.Applications, c => c.ApplicationId, a => a.ApplicationId,
                            (c, a) => a.ProjectId).Contains(p.ProjectId)).ToList();
```

Here is the answer :)